# Rails 3.1.1 HTTP streaming with Apache + Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, http-streaming

In the Railscasts about HTTP streaming some commenters have confirmed that one can do http streaming with Apache + Passenger but strangely I can't find any instructions via Google.

Also the Rails doc did not provide any instructions. All detailed instructions everywhere refer to Unicorn. I must not be the only one wanted to do http streaming over Apache and Passenger. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Streaming is more correctly known as [Chunked Transfer Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding).

These are the things I know about (there may be more requirements):

**Ruby 1.9.x**

Streaming requires the threading features of Ruby 1.9

**Compatible middleware**

Any middleware you have must not modify the HTTP response

**Passenger**

The passenger_buffer_response option must be turned off

**Client Support**

The client must advertise it uses HTTP 1.1 or send the TE request header.

I vaguely recall reading somewhere that nginx was needed, but I cannot find the reference anywhere.

I hope that helps.

Comment: The PassengerBufferResponse option becomes an issue in Passenger 3.0.11 http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerBufferResponse

Answer (score 0):

I just set up Passenger under Apache with response streaming yesterday and had no trouble.  Here is my virtual host config in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName www.my.site.com
  DocumentRoot /var/rails/myapp/public    
  <Directory /var/rails/myapp/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
     # Enable response streaming
     PassengerBufferResponse off
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```